# Outlook 2010, windows 64 bit, cannot send email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

everything has been working fine for 10+ months until last night.
email still being received, cannot send.
error message: oX8004010f, Outlook data file cannot be accessed.

Ran scanpst.  no help.

Comment: Does the file even exist?

Comment: Here is response from Outlook MVP on Microsoft site: ***#1 - There is no error message shown that "exclusively" displays "Error 0x8004010F"
#2 - The assumption appears that error codes included as part of an error message only apply to one cause which are presented under only one circumstance - neither of which is correct.*** other sites suggest error is from something failing to synchronize. If you are using exchange server, I would delete profile and create it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try MFCMAPI to repair your outlook profile.
MFCMAPI is a free tool hosted on CodePlex which is the Open Source Community from Microsoft.

It's available at http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

A few questions,

1. What type of email account (POP, IMAP, Exchange) are you using outlook with?
2. Do you have any rules configured in outlook to automatically copy email to a particular folder after you send?   It sort of sounds like this might be the issue.
3. Can you open the PST (or if you have more than one PST file, can you open all of them?)?   Any errors when browsing the PST?

It sounds to me like you have a rule in outlook that is configured to copy email when you send it to some PST folder.   Let me know if this is the case or not.   If it is, try to uncheck that rule temporarily via the Rules window and attempt to send out an email and see if that resolves the issue.

If that does not work, try to uncheck all of the rules (which will temporarily disable them, I do not suggest deleting any rules).

Please respond back with any additional details you can supply to assist in resolving your issue.